# c++ get number of objects built in class

Tags: c++, class

H there,
In the constructors of this class the value of m_id is increased by one, thus counting how many ports are constructed. However, I am trying to access the value of s_id independently, that is without 'getting' an object. Is there away of doing this? I have enclosed the code. I apologise in advance if this is an insufficiently specific question.
Thank you for taking the time to have a look.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Port
{
public:
    // Default constructor 
    Port():m_state(false), m_month("     "), m_id( generateID() )
    {}

    // Value constructor
    Port(bool state, std::string month) : m_state(state), m_month(month),    m_id( generateID() )
    {}

    // Getter
    void getPort() const
    {
        std::cout << "Port : " << std::boolalpha << m_state
        << " \tMonth : " << m_month
        << "\tUnique ID : " << m_id << '\n';
    }

    // Putter
    void putPort(bool state, std::string month)
    {
        m_state = state;
        m_month = month;
    }

private:
    static int s_id;      // static counter
    int m_id;             // counter value of object
    bool m_state;         // bool for state of port
    std::string m_month;  // month port turned on

    // method to create counter value of object
    int generateID ()     
    {
        static int s_id = 0;
        return ++s_id;
    }
};

int main() {

    Port port1;
    Port port2(true, "March");

    port1.getPort();
    port2.getPort();

    port1.putPort(true, "March");

    port1.getPort();
    port2.getPort();

    Port port3;
    Port port4;

    port3.getPort();
    port4.getPort();

    // This is where I get stuck?
    //std::cout << "Number of ports : " ????;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add static public method:

```
static int GetID() {
   return s_id;
}
```

then call it:

```
Port::GetID()
```

to get your s_id

Comment: (Sorry having trouble formatting the text in this comment box, total newbie!) I tried adding a static class member and then accessing through std::cout << Port::GetID() as suggested however I am receiving the following error message in Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Port::s_id", referenced from:
      Port::GetID() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @alexi2 Looks like linker error, you have not defined your s_id variable. Take a look at the following example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/956b5142e3fb06e2

Answer (score 2):

First, you probably want to use `std::atomic` if you're working in a multi-threaded system.

Second, you're "problem" is that you defined `s_id` as private. If you change it to public or have a public static function to access it you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access static class members without a class instance.

```
Port::s_id
```

You'll have to make it `public`, or provide a static accessor function, though.